# How to use multiple Docker containers to set up Jenkins agent in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

The following snippet is an example provided by Cypress, a Javascript testing framework that I'm using. Here is the [link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/Jenkinsfile) to the Github page.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    // this image provides everything needed to run Cypress
    docker {
      image 'cypress/base:10'
    }
  }

  stages {
    // first stage installs node dependencies and Cypress binary
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        // there a few default environment variables on Jenkins
        // on local Jenkins machine (assuming port 8080) see
        // http://localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env
        echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
        sh 'npm ci'
        sh 'npm run cy:verify'
      }
    }

    stage('start local server') {
      steps {
        // start local server in the background
        // we will shut it down in "post" command block
        sh 'nohup npm run start:ci &'
      }
    }

    // this stage runs end-to-end tests, and each agent uses the workspace
    // from the previous stage
    stage('cypress parallel tests') {
      environment {
        // we will be recording test results and video on Cypress dashboard
        // to record we need to set an environment variable
        // we can load the record key variable from credentials store
        // see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/
        CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY = credentials('cypress-example-kitchensink-record-key')
        // because parallel steps share the workspace they might race to delete
        // screenshots and videos folders. Tell Cypress not to delete these folders
        CYPRESS_trashAssetsBeforeRuns = 'false'
      }

      // https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel
      parallel {
        // start several test jobs in parallel, and they all
        // will use Cypress Dashboard to load balance any found spec files
        stage('tester A') {
          steps {
            echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            sh "npm run e2e:record:parallel"
          }
        }

        // second tester runs the same command
        stage('tester B') {
          steps {
            echo "Running build ${env.BUILD_ID}"
            sh "npm run e2e:record:parallel"
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  post {
    // shutdown the server running in the background
    always {
      echo 'Stopping local server'
      sh 'pkill -f http-server'
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to have a Jenkinsfile that is very similar to the above because I want to have parallel Cypress testing as shown in the above snippet. In the example above, the Jenkins agent is simply the official Cypress Docker image `cypress/base:10`.

```
  agent {
    // this image provides everything needed to run Cypress
    docker {
      image 'cypress/base:10'
    }
  }
```

However, for me to run all my tests with my own database, I need to spin up two separate Docker containers. One container contains the front-end portion of my web app and the other container contains the back-end portion of my web app.

Below is the Dockerfile for my front-end container, which is located in `my-app/docker/combined/Dockerfile`.

```
FROM cypress/included:3.4.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

RUN npm install -g history-server nodemon

RUN npm run build-test

EXPOSE 8080
```

Below is the Dockerfile for my back-end container, which is located in `my-app/docker/db/Dockerfile`. All it is doing is copying some local data into the Docker container and then initialising my MongoDB database with this data.

```
FROM  mongo:3.6.14-xenial

COPY ./dump/ /tmp/dump/

COPY mongo_restore.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_restore.sh
```

Usually, I would use `docker-compose` and the following `docker-compose.yml` file to spin up these two containers. As you can see, the front-end container called "combined" is dependent on the back-end container called "db".

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/db/Dockerfile
        container_name: b-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:     
            - dbdata:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - app-network

    combined:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/combined/Dockerfile
        container_name: b-combined
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - db
```

Below is the docker-compose command I would use.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

**I would like my Jenkins agent to be the `combined` container; however, I need the `combined` container to connect to my `db` container, which needs to be spun up. My question is, how do I achieve this in Jenkins pipelines? I've read [this documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/); however, it doesn't mention anything about using multiple Dockerfiles to create a Jenkins agent. Is something like this possible and could someone please show me what my Jenkinsfile should look like in order to achieve my goal?**

Comment: As for q3 2021 this is generally not possible. The alternative is to use kubernetes where agents are pods with multiple containers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running "sidecar" containers:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can communicate between the parallel builds, the thing is, that stages running in different `parallel` stages on the Jenkinsfile can theoretically be run on different Jenkins slaves, thus not being able to communicate with one another.

What I would recommend doing is to run both the server and the frontend application in parallel on the same stage using `&` and then calling `wait` to wait for all processes to exit.

You can even discard the usage of the `docker` keyword in the Jenkinsfile, and instead, call docker inside the stage itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think there might be some misunderstanding regarding the parallel builds. I don't mind if parallel builds cannot communicate with each other. I would simply like to have an agent that is comprised of `combined` and `db`. At this stage, I would just like to emulate the provided Jenkinsfile example from Cypress to test out parallel builds on my app.